# Why textbox is not appearing on Clicking the CREDIT/DEBIT radiobutton in C# .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

And this is my aspx.cs file

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.Visible = true;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.ReadOnly = false;
}

protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.Visible = false;
}
```

Why does the textbox not appear when the CREDIT/DEBIT `radioButton` is checked?

Comment: What is "CREDIT/DEBIT" `radiobutton` ? We can't help you without a view of your `.aspx` code.

Comment: post your aspx code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use  `AutoPostBack="true"` and you can use the below code. Its working

**Aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Stack_Overflow.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Text="Credit" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" GroupName="a">

        </asp:RadioButton>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Text="Debit" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton2_CheckedChanged" GroupName="a" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**code behind file**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Stack_Overflow
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label6.Visible = true;
            Label7.Visible = true;
            Label8.Visible = true;
            TextBox2.Visible = true;
            TextBox3.Visible = true;
            TextBox4.Visible = true;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.ReadOnly = false;
        }

        protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label6.Visible = false;
            Label7.Visible = false;
            Label8.Visible = false;
            TextBox2.Visible = false;
            TextBox3.Visible = false;
            TextBox4.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

do let me know in case you face any issue

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working fine